# How does Server.call work in elixir-mongo?

Tags: mongodb, elixir, gen-server

I'm learning Elixir and attempting to use the [elixir-mongo library](https://github.com/checkiz/elixir-mongo).  During the [auth/1](https://github.com/checkiz/elixir-mongo/blob/master/lib/mongo_db.ex#L42) command, A the function uses Server.call, piping in the MongoDB request string. looking at the Mongo.Server class, it does not appear to be an actual genserver, nor have a method to match call/1.  How is this working?

Answer (score 1):

With high probability it doesn't work. `Mongo.Server` module doesn't export `call` function. There are no macros that generate it magically. My guess is that master branch is currently broken. If you are using the library and want to dig into the sources make sure you are looking at the same tag as the version you are using in your project.

Also, there are no classes and methods in Elixir. There are modules and functions :)